# Put icon in the same line with text in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to put in the same line the icons with the coresponding text which now is below them but I cannot make it work.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Selections",
        column(6,
               fluidRow(
                 column(1,
                        icon("calendar")),
                 column(11,
                        uiOutput("date1date2")))),
        column(6,
               fluidRow(
                 column(1,
                        icon("bars")),
                 column(11,
                        uiOutput("prdttx"))))
        
    )
      )
      )


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$date1date2<-renderText({
    "fdsfsdfffs"
  })
  output$prdttx<-renderText({
    "fdsfsdfffs"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you mean the icon and text on the same line as the box title "Selections"?

Comment: no just icon and text

Comment: the easiest fix is to reduce the column width from 11 to 10

Comment: This is sensitive to the browser width: for me it starts as inline, but when I shrink the browser window it is no longer inline. I don't know how to guarantee it, but one problem you can fix is that your first level of `column(.)` is defined with `width=6`, yet your inner columns go out to `width=11`; if you reduce that 11 to 5, it holds out longer. Further, if you set `box(width=12, title="Selections",...)`, it holds out a little longer.

Comment: I would render a HTML span containing the icon and the text.

Comment: hmm yes a permamnet solution  regardless of browser width would be better